# PyOWM Chance of rain

Tags: python, weather-api

Getting this PyOWM module to work pretty well, understanding it a lot better, but I'm trying to find a way to get the percentage/chance of rain. It's just saying rain/light rain, doesn't say the % it will rain

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM(owm_api_key)
fc = owm.daily_forecast('Oklahoma City,US', 8)
tomorrow = fc.get_weather_at('2017-04-04 18:00:00+00')
print(tomorrow.get_rain())
# {'all': 1.73}
print(tomorrow.get_detailed_status())
# light rain
```

Unsure if OWM doesn't support chance of rain or if there's some member of the forecast class I'm missing.
[pyowm](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm)
[open weather map api](http://openweathermap.org/api)

Comment: Try using tags related to the question. This hasn't anything to do with pygame, fonts or dimensions. Also, since few of us have this module you'd benefit by writing what the print statements give you, because someone might be able to figure out an answer based on that information. Including a link to the documentation of the module will help as well. And make sure you've tried to find the answer in the documentation first.

Comment: Sorry, it was late, I was tired. Changed the tags, added, the print statement, and included a link to the pyowm module

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a chance of rain in the owm api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like there's a chance of rain in the owm api, nothing to do with pyowm.